# Is there a way to distinguish which CMake Tools Kit is chosen in the settings.json of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Is there a way to distinguish, which cmake-kits are selected in the settings.json of VS Code?

For example I want to do something like that (this is not working).

.vscode/cmake-kits.json:

```
[
    {
      "name": "SDK",
      "toolchainFile": "${workspaceFolder}/toolchain/SDK.cmake"
    }
]
```

settings.json

```
{
    "[SDK]":{
        "cmake.cmakePath":"${workspaceFolder}/cmake.sh"
    }
    
}
```

To be precise I want to execute a script, when the SDK is selected and I do not want to execute it, when the local compiler is selected.

Comment: the syntax you're using in your hypothetical `"[SDK]": {...}` is extremely confusing. That's the syntax for [language-mode overrides of settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings). Whereas you're thinking of "SDK" as a CMake Tools Kit name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want with modifying a VS Code setting based on the selected CMake Kits in the way that you're leading the question, you'd want to look in the direction of variable substitution, where you'd find [several variables provided by the CMake Tools extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#variable-substitution) for build kits. Unfortunately, this is a dead end. There is currently no way to set a VS Code setting conditioned upon the value of a variable. I'm not aware of a way to get any further with CMake Tools Kits.

What I would instead suggest that you do is use CMake Presets, which support a `cmakeExecutable` property in [the `configurePreset` entry schema](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset). The CMake Tools extension [has pretty good support for CMake Presets](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-presets.md), and you get the additional benefit that CMake Presets are not an IDE/IDE-extension-specific feature, but rather a CMake feature (unlike CMake Tools Kits, which are specific to CMake Tools).